# Is there a name for an idiom that intentionally reverses key words for dramatic effect?

Tags: idioms

I have in mind a particular kind of expression which employs a repeated sentence structure, but with key words reversed for dramatic or emphatic effect. Here are two examples:

- "It's not the size of the **dog** in the **fight**, it's the size of the **fight** in the **dog**"
- JFK's famous "ask not what **your country** can do for **you** — ask what **you** can do for **your country**"

In both cases, the words in **bold** have been reversed to reveal a deeper or more profound truth. Does this particular kind of idiom or expression have a formal name?

Comment: Your examples are not idioms.  (look it up)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is *antimetabole*.

"In rhetoric, antimetabole (/æntɪməˈtæbəliː/ AN-ti-mə-TAB-ə-lee) is the repetition of words in successive clauses, but in transposed order; for example, "I know what I like, and I like what I know"."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole

Honestly I always thought it was *chiasmus* - but apparently it is not.

"In rhetoric, chiasmus or, less commonly, chiasm (Latin term from Greek χίασμα, "crossing", from the Greek χιάζω, chiázō, "to shape like the letter Χ") is a "reversal of grammatical structures in successive phrases or clauses – but no repetition of words"...."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus

I'm pretty sure the JFK line is used as a standard example of chiasmus, but the correct term is antimetabole.

Comment: Yes, I think the specific term is antimetabole. Thanks,

Comment: There are so many of them that it can get confusing. Well done, though.

Comment: "It's not who answers the question, it's who questions the answer."

Comment: Yes, John, and I am grateful that my answer was questioned. I not only learned something myself, I was able to correct the wrong information I had originally posted.