# Which literary device swaps ideas between clauses?

Tags: literary-device, poetic-devices

While thinking of an appropriate inscription for my dad’s headstone, the following phrase came to mind: “He served his country with honor, and honored his wife with love.” Can this sentence be described as being an example of any particular kind of literary or poetic device?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't answer **this** question, because the sentence here does not swap the exact words, but similar ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It's a form of [*parallelism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(rhetoric)), but it's not *antimetabolism* which is explained in [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/517455/is-there-a-name-for-an-idiom-that-intentionally-reverses-key-words-for-dramatic) as a definite symmetry, swapping the terms.

A specific device which doesn't simply swap words around and does use synonyms is [***chiasmus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus).